# Is OpenVas supported on Windows OS?

Tags: windows, openvas

Is there a new version of OpenVas (version 8 or above) which is supported on Windows OS?

If so, Where can I download it from and install it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Answer from OpenVas:

> OpenVAS will not run on Windows unless you run its Linux-VM in a
>   hypervisor on  Windows. Scanning of Windows is of course possible.